# Dijkstra adjacency list

Tags: java, algorithm, dijkstra, adjacency-list

I have run into a problem converting pseudocode of Dijkstras algorithm into actual code. I was given and adjacency list such as "Location - adjacent location - distance to location," example for one node: AAA AAC 180  AAD 242  AAH 40.
My task was to read a file organized as adjacency list as described, and compute the shortest path from one node to another. 
Here is the Dijkstra pseudocode:

```
    void dijkstra( Vertex s )
    {
        for each Vertex v
        {
          v.dist = INFINITY;
          v.known = false;
        }
      s.dist = 0;
        while( there is an unknown distance vertex )
         {
          Vertex v = smallest unknown distance vertex;
          v.known = true;

         for each Vertex w adjacent to v
          if( !w.known )
           {
           DistType cvw = cost of edge from v to w;
           if( v.dist + cvw < w.dist )
             {
    // Update w
           decrease( w.dist to v.dist + cvw );
           w.path = v;
             }
            }
           }
    }
```

im having the most trouble with the line "for each Vertex w adjacent to v"
Here is my nonworking code:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ListIterator;

public class Dijkstra {

    public static boolean isInteger(String s) {
        return isInteger(s, 10);
    }

    public static boolean isInteger(String s, int radix) {
        if (s.isEmpty())
            return false;
        for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
            if (i == 0 && s.charAt(i) == '-') {
                if (s.length() == 1)
                    return false;
                else
                    continue;
            }
            if (Character.digit(s.charAt(i), radix) < 0)
                return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    public static void dijkstra(Vertex[] a, Vertex s, int lineCount) {
        int i = 0;
        while (i < (lineCount)) // each Vertex v
        {
            a[i].dist = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
            a[i].known = false;
            i++;
        }

        s.dist = 0;
        int min = Integer.MAX_VALUE; //

        while (!(a[0].known == true && a[1].known == true && a[2].known == true && a[3].known == true
                && a[4].known == true && a[5].known == true && a[6].known == true && a[7].known == true
                && a[8].known == true && a[9].known == true && a[10].known == true && a[11].known == true
                && a[12].known == true)) {
            System.out.println("here");
            for (int b = 0; b < lineCount; b++) {

                if (a[b].dist < min && a[b].known == false) {
                    min = a[b].dist;
                }
            }
            int c = 0;
            while (c < lineCount) {

                if (a[c].dist == min && a[c].known == false) {
                    break;
                }
                c++;
            }
            System.out.println(min);

            a[c].known = true;
            int adjSize = a[c].adj.size();

            int current = 0;

            System.out.println(adjSize);

            while (current < adjSize - 1) {

                String currentAdjacent = (String) a[c].adj.get(current);
                int p = 0;

                while (p < lineCount) {
                    if (a[p].name.equals(currentAdjacent)) {

                        if (!a[p].known) {
                            String cvwString = (String) a[c].distance.get(current);
                            int cvw = Integer.parseInt(cvwString);
                            System.out.println(" This is cvw" + cvw);
                            System.out.println("Here2");

                            if (a[c].dist + cvw < a[p].dist) {
                                a[p].dist = a[c].dist + cvw;
                                a[p].path = a[c];
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    p++;
                }
                current++;
            }
        }
    }

    public static class Vertex {
        public List adj; // Adjacency list
        public List distance;
        public boolean known;
        public int dist; // DistType is probably int
        public Vertex path;
        public String name;

        // Other fields and methods as needed
    }

    public static void printPath(Vertex v) {
        if (v.path != null) {
            printPath(v.path);
            System.out.print(" to ");
        }
        System.out.print(v);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        int lineCounter = 0;

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("airport.txt"));
        try {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = br.readLine();

            while (line != null) {

                sb.append(line);
                sb.append(System.lineSeparator());
                line = br.readLine();

                lineCounter = lineCounter + 1;
            }

            Vertex[] arr = new Vertex[lineCounter];
            for (int i = 0; i < lineCounter; i++) {
                arr[i] = new Vertex();
                arr[i].adj = new LinkedList<String>();
                arr[i].distance = new LinkedList<Integer>();
            }
            ;

            //
            int arrayCounter = 0;
            String everything = sb.toString();
            String[] lines = everything.split("\\s*\\r?\\n\\s*");

            for (String line1 : lines) {
                arr[arrayCounter] = new Vertex();

                arr[arrayCounter].adj = new LinkedList<String>();
                arr[arrayCounter].distance = new LinkedList<Integer>();
                String[] result = line1.split("\\s+");

                for (int x = 0; x < result.length; x++) {
                    if (x == 0) {
                        arr[arrayCounter].name = result[0];
                        continue;
                    } else if (isInteger(result[x])) {
                        arr[arrayCounter].distance.add(result[x]);
                        continue;
                    } else {
                        arr[arrayCounter].adj.add(result[x]);
                        continue;
                    }
                }

                arrayCounter++;
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
                System.out.println(arr[i].name);
            }
            System.out.println(lineCounter);
            dijkstra(arr, arr[3], lineCounter - 1);
            printPath(arr[11]);

        } finally {
            br.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Using my vertex class as is I was using a series of while loops to first, traverse the adjacency strings stored in a linked list while comparing to see which vertex is equivalent to the adjacency list string. Is there a better way to code "for each Vertex w adjacent to v" using my Vertex class? And apologies ahead for messy code and any others style sins i may have committed. Thanks!

Comment: Having nested structures with no indentation makes code almost unreadable. Please consider correcting the formatting of the first code block.

Comment: Ok, should be formatted better now.

Comment: Why not just implement `isInteger` using `s.matches("^-?[0-9]+")`? Why do you need to consider the radix? (you never pass anything except 10, implicitly)

Comment: @panzerschwein the indentation is still poor. Please format all of the code.

Comment: Beginner but that does seem to be more concise.

Comment: @AndyTurner  tried my best but don't think i can format any further. It is just unreadable? No one thinks they see what my issue is?

Comment: Formatting your code should be very easy. If nothing else, let your favorite IDE format it for you, copy it, paste it here, and with the code selected click the `{ }` button on the menu bar in the editor.

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils Ok I used the IDE format. Hopefully it is formatted satisfactorily now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve this problem you need a bunch of "Node" objects, stored in a HashMap, keyed on Source Location.

In the node, you need a collection of references to adjacent "Node" objects (or at least their "key" so you can write logic against it.  The "Node" also needs to know it's location and distance to each "adjacent" node.   Think Lundon Underground Tube Maps - each station connects to at least one other station.  Usually two or more.   Therefore, adjacent nodes to tube stations are the immediate next stops you can get to from that station.

Once you have that data structure in place, you can then use a recursive routine to iterate through each individual node.  It should then iterate through each child node (aka adjacent node), and track distances from the initial (source) node to the current node by storing this data in a HashMap and using the current accumulated distance whilst recursing (or "walking" the graph"). This tracking information should be part of your method signature when recursing.   You will also need to track the current path you have taken when recursing, in order to avoid circular loops (which will ultimately and ironically cause a StackOverflowError).  You can do this by using a HashSet.  This Set should track the source and current node's location as the entry key.    If you see this present during your recursion, then you have already seen it, so don't continue processing.

I'm not going to code the solution for you because I suspect that you ask more specific questions as you work your way through understanding the answer, which are very likely answered elsewhere.